# IBD problem: Reindexing blocks and syncing starts over every time I shut and open Core

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, synchronization

I am currently doing IBD in segments due to logistical reasons, but each time I safely shut down Core and unplug my hard drive (HDD, 1TB) and then plug it back in and start up Core, it starts in 2009 and reindexes all blocks on disk. I've finished all indexing in one go, and still had to redo it for some reason.

I'm using v 0.19.01 on a Windows 10 computer.

Comment: Do you have reindex=1 in your bitcoin.conf, or any possibly related settings in the config file at all?

Comment: My bitcoin.conf is empty (I'm using GUI). Is that correct or am I looking at the wrong bitcoin.conf file? I installed core and ran it without changing any settings. Should I type in a certain reindex value in the file?

Comment: Can you include your debug.log file? You can post it to a site like pastebin.com and put the link here if it is too big to fit in a post.

Comment: This is my debug.log. I'm seeing the checksum fails, and a corruption message. Does this mean my drive is corrupting? It has done this 3 or 4 times now in the same way every time. I'm also seeing the error "Error opening block database, do you want to rebuild the block db now?"     https://pastebin.com/PEDEeafb